# Title: Issue with the Execution of the makeAttacks Function within a WebSocket Context

Tags: javascript, websocket, async-await, web3js

I am currently facing an issue with a part of my code where I am trying to execute the makeAttacks function within a WebSocket context, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Here's the relevant code:

const processTransaction = async () => {
// The WebSocket always executes the initialChecksTest function to search and find the sandwich
const checksPassed = await initialChecksTest(tx);
if (!checksPassed) return false;
const {
transaction,
amountIn, // Victim's ETH
minAmountOut,
tokenToCapture,
} = checksPassed;

```
console.log("------------------- I WISH TO START ATTACKS PROCESS -----------------");
console.log('checks passed', tx);
// TODO: Exit execution of the initialChecksTest(tx) function
// Log when the WebSocket connection is opened
// Log WebSocket errors
wsProvidermainnet.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
});
console.log("******************** END START ATTACKS PROCESS ************************");

// The WebSocket doesn't execute the makeAttacks function!
if (checksPassed) makeAttacks(transaction, amountIn, minAmountOut, tokenToCapture);
```

}

const start = async () => {
try {
flashbotsProvider = await FlashbotsBundleProvider.create(providermainnet, signingWalletReal, flashbotsUrlReal);
console.log('Flashbots provider initialized.');

```
    // Set up an event listener for pending transactions
    wsProvidermainnet.on('pending', async tx => {
        try {
            // Perform initial checks on the transaction
            processTransaction(tx);
            // console.log('Initial checks passed for transaction:', tx, '');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error processing transaction:', error);
        }
    });
    console.log('Listening for pending transactions on chain ID', chainId);
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error initializing Flashbots provider:', error);
}
```

};

// Call the start function
start();

The problem I'm observing is that the makeAttacks function is not executed when the if (checksPassed) condition is true. I expect this function to be called at this stage, but it doesn't happen. I have verified that checksPassed is defined and meets the required conditions.

Do you have any insights into what might be causing this unexpected behavior? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried to close websocket to run the makeAttacks function and launch it again but didnt work for me.

Comment: Could I see the `initialChecksTest()` function? Also, at `strat()` function, you're passing the `tx` arg to the `processTransaction`, but it seems like you're not taking that param in the function declaration. Could this be causing the function to exit on `if (!checksPassed) return false`? Just wondering.